# Problems testing values saved in android Intent (extras always null)

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-intent

I have the following Android Intent extension:

```kotlin
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Parcelable
import java.io.Serializable

fun Intent.addNewTaskFlags(): Intent = apply {
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
}

fun Intent.putData(dataMap: Map<String, Any?>): Intent = apply {
    dataMap.forEach { (key, data) ->
        data?.let {
            put(key, it)
        }
    }
}

private fun Intent.put(key: String, value: Any) {
    when (value) {
        is String -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Int -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Boolean -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Long -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Double -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Parcelable -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Serializable -> putExtra(key, value)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Incompatible data type: ${value.javaClass}")
    }
}
```

And the following unit test:

```kotlin
class IntentExtensionTest {

    @Test
    fun testAddNewTaskFlags() {
        // When
        val mockIntent = spyk(Intent())
        mockIntent.addNewTaskFlags()

        // Then
        verify {
            mockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testPutData() {
        // Given
        val parcelableValue = mockk<Parcelable>()
        val serializableValue = mockk<Serializable>()

        // When
        val intent = Intent().putData(
            mapOf(
                STRING_KEY to STRING_VALUE,
                INT_KEY to INT_VALUE,
                BOOLEAN_KEY to BOOLEAN_VALUE,
                LONG_KEY to LONG_VALUE,
                DOUBLE_KEY to DOUBLE_VALUE,
                PARCELABLE_KEY to parcelableValue,
                SERIALIZABLE_KEY to serializableValue
            )
        )

        // Then
        intent.run {
            val extras = extras ?: throw AssertionError("Intent extras are null")

            assertEquals(STRING_VALUE, extras.getString(STRING_KEY))
            assertEquals(INT_VALUE, extras.getInt(INT_KEY, -1))
            assertEquals(BOOLEAN_VALUE, extras.getBoolean(BOOLEAN_KEY, false))
            assertEquals(LONG_VALUE, extras.getLong(LONG_KEY, -1L))
            assertEquals(DOUBLE_VALUE, extras.getDouble(DOUBLE_KEY, -1.0))
            assertEquals(parcelableValue, extras.getParcelable(PARCELABLE_KEY))
            assertEquals(serializableValue, extras.getSerializable(SERIALIZABLE_KEY))
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val STRING_KEY = "stringKey"
        private const val STRING_VALUE = "Hello, World!"
        private const val INT_KEY = "intKey"
        private const val INT_VALUE = 1
        private const val BOOLEAN_KEY = "booleanKey"
        private const val BOOLEAN_VALUE = true
        private const val LONG_KEY = "longKey"
        private const val LONG_VALUE = 123456789L
        private const val DOUBLE_KEY = "doubleKey"
        private const val DOUBLE_VALUE = 3.14
        private const val PARCELABLE_KEY = "parcelableKey"
        private const val SERIALIZABLE_KEY = "serializableKey"
    }
}
```

The test `testPutData` is falling with the error:

```
Intent extras are null
java.lang.AssertionError: Intent extras are null
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Just looking at the code I don't see anything wrong. Hmm... Did you try running the test in debug mode and actually looking at the `Intent` instance after you call `putData()` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's Intent class (as well as many other classes in the Android framework) has behavior that isn't just pure Java. These classes sometimes contain native or system-level code or depend on the Android runtime environment. This means they can't be tested with traditional JVM-based unit testing frameworks like JUnit in isolation. When you try to use such classes directly in a JUnit test, you'll often get unexpected errors or behavior.

Robolectric is a library designed to let you test Android-specific code on the JVM. It provides shadow objects (shadows) for many of Android's classes. These shadows simulate the behavior of the real Android classes, making it possible to test Android code on your development machine without an emulator or device.

The *Intent extras are null* error, it was likely because the vanilla JVM didn't know how to handle the Android-specific behavior of the Intent class. By using Robolectric:

- **Android Runtime Simulation:** Robolectric sets up a simulated Android runtime environment, which allows the `Intent` and its methods to operate as they would on a real Android device or emulator.
- **Shadow Classes:** Robolectric provides "shadow" implementations of many Android framework classes. When your tests call methods on these classes, they're actually calling methods on Robolectric's shadow objects, which mimic the behavior of the real classes.
- **Real Behavior without Emulators:** Without Robolectric, to test this kind of behavior, you'd typically need to run the test on an Android emulator or a physical device, which would be slower and more cumbersome. Robolectric allows for quicker feedback and faster test execution.

I resolved this problem using roboletric, putting this above the test class signature:

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.R])
```

The complete file is:

```kotlin
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.mercadopago.selling.utils.extensions.addNewTaskFlags
import com.mercadopago.selling.utils.extensions.putData
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.spyk
import io.mockk.verify
import java.io.Serializable
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.R])
class IntentExtensionTest {

    @Test
    fun testAddNewTaskFlags() {
        // When
        val mockIntent = spyk(Intent())
        mockIntent.addNewTaskFlags()

        // Then
        verify {
            mockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testPutData() {
        // Given
        val parcelableValue = mockk<Parcelable>()
        val serializableValue = mockk<Serializable>()

        // When
        val intent = Intent().putData(
            mapOf(
                STRING_KEY to STRING_VALUE,
                INT_KEY to INT_VALUE,
                BOOLEAN_KEY to BOOLEAN_VALUE,
                LONG_KEY to LONG_VALUE,
                DOUBLE_KEY to DOUBLE_VALUE,
                PARCELABLE_KEY to parcelableValue,
                SERIALIZABLE_KEY to serializableValue
            )
        )

        // Then
        intent.run {
            val extras = extras ?: throw AssertionError("Intent extras are null")

            assertEquals(STRING_VALUE, extras.getString(STRING_KEY))
            assertEquals(INT_VALUE, extras.getInt(INT_KEY, -1))
            assertEquals(BOOLEAN_VALUE, extras.getBoolean(BOOLEAN_KEY, false))
            assertEquals(LONG_VALUE, extras.getLong(LONG_KEY, -1L))
            assertEquals(DOUBLE_VALUE, extras.getDouble(DOUBLE_KEY, -1.0), epsilon)
            assertEquals(parcelableValue, extras.getParcelable(PARCELABLE_KEY))
            assertEquals(serializableValue, extras.getSerializable(SERIALIZABLE_KEY))
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val STRING_KEY = "stringKey"
        private const val STRING_VALUE = "Hello, World!"
        private const val INT_KEY = "intKey"
        private const val INT_VALUE = 1
        private const val BOOLEAN_KEY = "booleanKey"
        private const val BOOLEAN_VALUE = true
        private const val LONG_KEY = "longKey"
        private const val LONG_VALUE = 123456789L
        private const val DOUBLE_KEY = "doubleKey"
        private const val DOUBLE_VALUE = 3.14
        private const val PARCELABLE_KEY = "parcelableKey"
        private const val SERIALIZABLE_KEY = "serializableKey"
        private const val epsilon = 1e-6
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, correct. Sorry. I was assuming that `Intent` (at least the parts you were trying to test) was just a container. After looking at the source for for the Anroid `Intent` class, I see that a lot of the methods are delegated to internal Android framework implementations, which obviously won't work in the test scenario. Looks like you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the reason of this behavior is described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#mocking-dependencies).

> However, a local test can't use `Context` or any of its methods as they belong to the Android framework.

In your case it's `Intent` that is not mocked.

You might be using `unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true` as you're not getting the *Method putExtra in android.content.Intent not mocked* error. But with this config both `putExtra` does nothing and `extras` are null producing that `AssertionError`.

I think you may consider testing the behavior of the extension functions themselves rather than the indirect result of their invocations (i.e. the `extras` property in the `Intent`). The fact that `putExtras` modify the `extras` property is a part of `Intent` internal implementation thus is a matter of tests on the `Intent` class. But for the tests on these extension functions it's important how exactly those `Intent` methods are called – e.g. how many times, what args they were called with, but not the further impact, this is the meaning of isolation.

Comment: This makes no sense. In this case, `Intent` is the class under test. It should NOT be mocked. OP is creating a **real `Intent` instance**, which he then tests to validate his extension functions behaviour.

Comment: @DavidWasser Why? `Intent` is an external code. I believe one should test the interactions with it regardless of the results of these interactions. The latter is a matter of `Intent` class test coverage by the authors of its source code.

Comment: OP has written extensions to the `Intent` class. In this case, `Intent` **is the class under test**.

Comment: @DavidWasser would it be the same if we tested `Utils.putData(intent, data)`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The code is an extension of the `Intent` class. It has access to the private member variables and private method of `Intent`. If you moved that code to a `Utils` class, and you wanted to test it, you would somehow need to validate that the correct calls were made to the `Intent` class. In this case you wouldn't necessarily care about the internal implementation of the `Intent` class, and in this case you could mock the `Intent` class to verify the code.

Comment: @DavidWasser "It has access to the private member variables and private method of Intent."

No, in Kotlin, extension functions don't have access to private members. They are just a syntax sugar, and my Java example `Utils.putData(intent, data)` is equivalent to a top-level extension function in Kotlin. In non-top-level cases, it won't be static, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: Yep, you are correct and I am wrong. I stand corrected. You learn something new every day. Thanks.